# How to print a .rdlc (SSRS) report as duplex mode?

Tags: c#, printing, reporting-services

I need to print the report (.rdlc) in duplex mode. The report viewer always print the report in  ' Simplex mode'. I need to print my report in Duplex mode.

I have already rendered the report in to PDF.

Here is it:

```
 byte[] bytes = reportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

This report contains images as well as charecters !

If the report contains more than one page, i need to print it on the page one back side .
eg:

```
page 1 - paper 1 front side
page 2 - paper 1 back side
page 3 - paper 2 front side
page 4 - paper 2 back side.....................etc.
```

How can I print this report in Duplex Mode ...?
Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thanks for your support,

I got the solution from here  :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

Actually I am not showing the report viewer to the user to select the printing options. There is only one print button (Windows Application ) for the user to perform the printing action and all the functionality that I mentioned above will do internally by code.

I just tuned some logic from this code to perform the duplex mode printing and setting the paper size, and its works fine! !!

For the Printing  (for me it's A5 paper)  =>

```
 printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("PaperA5", 583, 827); 
 printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
 printDoc.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Vertical;
 printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
 printDoc.Print();
```

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

This is totally dependent on factors outside of your code's control. You need to rely on the setup of your printer which is unavailable in SSRS/C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You can print it in `Duplex Mode` using `C#`. Use `PrintDocument` class from `System.Drawing.Printing`.

```
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
printDoc.PrinterSettings.CanDuplex = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works with local reports using `ReportViewer` control:

```
Me.ctlReportViewer.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Printing.Duplex.Vertical
```